# Dynamically insert images into 'v-data-table'

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, slot, v-data-table

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :search="search"
  hide-default-footer
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template #[`item.employee_avatar`]="{ item }">
    <v-img
      :src="require('@/assets/img/img2.jpg')"
      :alt="item.name"
      style="width: 100px; height: 100px"
    />
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

The image with a fixed path is received, but I want to express the image with the image path of each object. I want to automatically follow the `imgsrc` path value of `items`.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      loading: true,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Avatar',
          value: 'employee_avatar',
          divider: true,
          align: 'center',
          sortable: false,
          width: '100px',
        },
        {
          text: 'myname',
          align: 'center',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
      ],
      items: [
        {
          name: 'myname',
          imgsrc: "@/assets/avatar.png",
        },
```

The code below is the code I tried.

```html
<template #[`item.employee_avatar`]="{ item }">
  <v-img
    :src="require(item.imgsrc)"
    :alt="item.name"
    style="width: 100px; height: 100px"
  />
</template>
```

There will be an error even if I fill out the above.

What's wrong with it? Help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-slot` instead of `#[item.employee_avatar]`:

```html
<template v-slot:item.employee_avatar="{ item }">
  <v-img
    :src="require(item.imgsrc)"
    :alt="item.name"
    style="width: 100px; height: 100px"
  />
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't `v-slot:item.employee_avatar="{ item }"` and `#[item.employee_avatar]="{ item }" ` the same thing?
Either way, the image is not displayed.

Comment: Maybe your image path is broken